# How can I add an image into SciLab's Gui Builder?

Tags: user-interface, window, scilab

I'm using Scilab's GUI Builder, and I know there's a button that lets you add an image, but it only generates a white square. How can I load an image I have saved from my computer? Not sure if it may be done using the GUI or if it's done through code. If it's the latter, can anyone help me with the code to use?

Thank you!!

Comment: What is you code so far? Do you use the appropriate image type (i.e .gif or .bmp) and size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an image to it using the GUI by simply setting its property "string" with the path of the image file you want to display, as written in the documentation: https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/fr_FR/uicontrol_properties.html